# Is the "first pass effect" diminished more by some foods than others?

Tags: human-biology, digestive-system, digestion

This effect and its considerations are [fairly well known](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/81118) but it's never been clear to me whether it's a greater consideration with some types of food than others.

Comment: This completely depends on drug in question.

Comment: @Jan I don't see how. My question doesn't ask the extent to which it happens; merely whether or not it happens at all. If any drug that experiences a first pass effect has that effect diminished more by some foods than others then the answer to my question is "yes."